# How to convert Floating Point into Decimal Java

Tags: java, binary, decimal

I would like to write a program that converts a floating point binary number into decimal. I know how to convert a normal binary number into decimal but I would like to convert a floating point binary into decimal with a mantissa of 10 and a exponent of 6.

At the same time I would like to use input to gain the binary value e.g.
`System.out.println("Enter a binary number");`
Then use a scanner to gain input. Is this possible?

Comment: Concerning `mantissa`, you might find [this](http://kipirvine.com/asm/workbook/floating_tut.htm) useful. And maybe [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Mantissa.html) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significand). And let the confusion begin.

Comment: Could you give an example in your question what you consider a floating point binary number, a decimal and a binary number? These definitions are ambiguous so it would be goo to know exactly what you mean so it can be answered properly. There is the definition of the numeric theory and the Java Language Specification.

Answer (score 2):

Given a `String` like `"101011.1011"`, one approach is:

1. Split the string into two bits using `String.split`.
2. Use the `BigInteger` constructor `BigInteger(String s, int radix)` with `radix == 2` to get the two `BigInteger`s representing `1010111011` and `10000`.
3. Use the `BigDecimal` constructor taking `BigInteger` to convert to `BigDecimal`.
4. Divide the answers.

I don't know if there's a simpler way.